# How to handle mobile viewport changes upon browser header/footer disappearance?

Tags: html, css, mobile

In mobile version of site I have modal window with 100% height with fixed footer, and the problem I have is the mobile viewport changes if user is trying to scroll this window somewhere. Mobile browsers acts differently, some of them is hiding header or footer (browser elements meant here), some of them hiding both. For a moment, before viewport size are finally changed, content below modal becomes visible, and that doesn't look nice at all. Is there a way to handle this behaviour?

Comment: can you please share sample code ?

Comment: You challanging people imagination without showing any code or picture. I kinda grasp what you mean but we can't help you without possibility to point you a problem. I could answer in the same manner as questions is asked.  Make background layer for modal and make it 200% of width and 200% of height with `overflow: hidden` and no matter what will be happining in the template it will hide it if modal is open.